# discord.py - Cannot get average colour of a user's avatar

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp, discord.py

So I have this function to return a user's avatar's average colour:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

class Bot(commands.Bot):

    ...

    @staticmethod
    async def get_average_colour(image_url, default=0x696969):
        try:
            resp = requests.get(image_url)
            assert resp.ok
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(resp.content))
            img2 = img.resize((1, 1), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            colour = img2.getpixel((0, 0))
            res = "{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(*colour)
            return int(res, 16)
        except:
            return default

    ...
```

This works, but the problem with this is that it uses [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master), which is blocking. So I tried using [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable) instead:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from PIL import Image
import aiohttp
from io import BytesIO

class Bot(commands.Bot):

    ...

    @staticmethod
    async def get_average_colour(image_url, default=0x696969):
        try:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(image_url) as resp:
                    if resp.status != 200:
                        raise Exception
                    img = Image.open(BytesIO(await resp.read()))
            colour = img.resize((1, 1), Image.ANTIALIAS).getpixel((0, 0))
            return int("{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(*colour), 16)
        except:
            return default

    ...
```

When I tried to find the average colour of a [random cat image link](http://aws.random.cat/meow), the function works fine, but when I try to call this function with a user's [`avatar_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.avatar_url), the function always return the default value. Does anyone know what's wrong with that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way would be to convert `image_url` to a string. That way it will always remain a string, a not a [`discord.Asset`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asset) object.